# Print random number of lines after read a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am writing a thread-enabled python program which can read a file and send, but is there any ways to let the program read and send N numbers of line at a time?

```
from random import randint
import sys
import threading
import time

def function():
    fo = open("1.txt", "r")
    print "Name of the file: ", fo.name

    while True:
        line = fo.readlines()
        for lines in line:
            print(lines)
            fo.seek(0, 0)
            time.sleep(randint(1,3))

game = threading.Thread(target=function)  
game.start()
```

The following python code only can let me send one line at a time, and then rewind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow your code logic, in the `for` loop iterating over the lines in the file, you reset the file pointer to the first line right after having printed it. That's why you get the same first line printed. To achieve a random number of printed lines you could do that in any number of ways, for example:

```
def function():
    fo = open("1.txt", "r")
    print "Name of the file: ", fo.name
    lines = fo.readlines()    # changed the var names, lines vs. line
    start_index = 0
    while True:
        length = randint(1, len(lines)-start_index)
        for line in lines[start_index:start_index+length]:
            print(line)
        start_index += length
        time.sleep(randint(1,3))
```

In there, after reading in the file content into `lines`, the code will loop on each line, but only until the n-th index, calculated via `randint(1, len(lines))`, and avoiding `0` so at the very least you get one line printed. After the print loop, we reset the file pointer, and sleep.

REVISION: given the new detail, at every cycle we are now randomizing the window of lines to be printed, while moving along the already printed lines. Basically a sliding window of random length at each iteration, making sure it (should) be consistent with the size of the array. Adjust as needed.

Comment: This one looks good, but every time it print out a list it will print start from 1st line after  time.sleep(randint(1,3)). Is there anywhere to make the next print start from where it last?

Comment: Of course there is a way, but it wasn't clear from the initial ask. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @不好笑 if this solved your problem, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
from random import randint
import sys
import threading
import time

def function():
    fo = open("1.txt", "r")
    print "Name of the file: ", fo.name
    lines = fo.readlines()
    while lines:
        toSend = ""
        for i in range(0,random.randint(x,y)): #plug your range in
            toSend += lines.pop(0)
        print(toSend)

game = threading.Thread(target=function)  
game.start()
```

Comment: You're almost there, just need to add on something.
I'm not sure where should I add the seek() method to let the program rewind while reading the file.